# Using Ranges Against a Dataset

Tags: python, binning

I am having a spot of trouble with a seemingly simple problem. I have a list of atom coordinates in the format X,Y,Z. I have used numpy.linspace() to make a list of 'bins' from the Z coordinates. The Z coordinates are such that the difference between points after they are sorted may only decimals or whole numbers. I would like to move over the 'bins' and only add in the X,Y,Z of the coordinate sets that fall in the range 'bin0'-'bin1' then 'bin1-bin2'. Basically this is what I would like to do in some really bad pseudocode. I already have the evenly spaced numbers that I want to use as 'bin' ranges

```
    1. Find XYZ coordinate sets that fall into first 'bin'
    2. Do math on them and save the value out
    3. Move on to next bin.
```

I know there is probably a simply python solution, but my understandings of list comprehensions working with ranges is limited. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

EDIT*
tried to add a "SSCCE"

```
import numpy as np
xyz = [[2,-2,0.29],[ -2,0,1.9 ],[2,1,2.35],[2,-3,2.96],[ 2,0,4.97],[0,3,5.13],[-1,3,5.41]]
bins = [0,0.57,1.14,1.71,2.28,2.85555556, 3.42, 3.99, 4.56,5.14]
'''Now I want to add all of the xyz's with a z-value between 0 and .57 a list or somthing      so that I can use them,
then I want to move on to the xyz's that fall between .57 and 1.14'''
workingXYZs = []
for x,y,z in xyz:
    for i in bins:
    if z > i: #but not greater than next I
       #do math and move on to next interval
```

Comment: Can you give us a short, self contained, correct example of your code and data? It is pretty unclear what you're asking for. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Using a list comprehension to isolate the useful data from the whole list is faster than using a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a list of tuples, you can easily use a list comprehension;

```
# I'm making up some data
In [13]: atoms = [(random.random(), random.random(), random.random()) for i in xrange(100)]

# Select every coordinate wher 0 < Z < 0.01
In [16]: [a for a in atoms if 0 <a[2]<0.01]
Out[16]: [(0.2118237642057983, 0.3740988439603703, 0.007613439427947566), (0.1982752864446785, 0.8253287086824319, 0.009925330198799487), (0.07769287016236548, 0.7685209005035492, 0.008550123528872411)]
```

Comment: I think I am onto something with np.digitize()